# Gitlab CI/CD Jobs fail but all is correct

Tags: shell, gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd

When my project's jobs run in the Gitlab pipeline, at the end of the testing job the job fails even though all the unit tests are good.

I don't understand why. Here's the architecture of my project:

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules
    - dist

default:
  image: node:lts

stages:
  - build
  - test

build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - bash ci/build/build_tools_install.sh
  script:
    - bash ci/build/build_app.sh

tests:
  stage: test
  variables:
    CI: "true"
  before_script:
    - bash ci/tests/tests_tools_install.sh
  script:
    - bash ci/tests/tests_run.sh
```

**tests_tools_install.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Display debug in console
set -xe

# Library to control Chrome, it contains Chrome
npm install puppeteer@18.0.0

# Add system libraries needed to start Chrome in Headless mode
apt update -yqq
apt install -yqq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
```

**tests_run.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash=

# Display debug in console
set -xe

# Set the CHROME_BIN variable to point to the Chrome binary
export CHROME_BIN=`find $CI_PROJECT_DIR/node_modules/puppeteer -name "chrome"`

# Start Angular tests using locally installed Angular CLI
node_modules/.bin/ng test --code-coverage=false --watch=false
```

**Gitlab test job console result**

```
04 07 2023 17:17:38.656:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox with concurrency unlimited
04 07 2023 17:17:38.659:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
04 07 2023 17:17:38.907:INFO [Chrome Headless 106.0.5249.0 (Linux x86_64)]: Connected on socket uFBxUufDl-2onOYIAAAB with id 77018412
Chrome Headless 106.0.5249.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 5 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome Headless 106.0.5249.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 5 (skipped 5) SUCCESS (0.023 secs / 0 secs)
TOTAL: 0 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 0 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 0 SUCCESS
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Branches     : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Functions    : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Lines        : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
================================================================================
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: Maybe it returns exit code 1 because 0 tests were run. Try to make at least one test to run.

Comment: Yes that was the answer..  I don't understand why the fact that 0 tests that return SUCCESS is a problem, but hey... it finally works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that, since I had 0 tests to run, the job fail even if it returned a "success".

Thank you @Vlad DX for pointing me in this direction, which didn't make sense to me at first.

```
Chrome Headless 106.0.5249.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 3 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome Headless 106.0.5249.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 1 of 3 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.078 secs)
Chrome Headless 106.0.5249.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 2 of 3 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.093 secs)
Chrome Headless 106.0.5249.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 3 of 3 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.103 secs)
Chrome Headless 106.0.5249.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 3 of 3 SUCCESS (0.149 secs / 0.103 secs)
TOTAL: 3 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 3 SUCCESS
TOTAL: 3 SUCCESS
=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Branches     : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Functions    : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Lines        : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
================================================================================
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
Saving cache for successful job
00:24
Creating cache default-non_protected...
node_modules: found 36969 matching artifact files and directories 
WARNING: dist: no matching files. Ensure that the artifact path is relative to the working directory (/foo/foo/foo) 
coverage: found 19 matching artifact files and directories 
Uploading cache.zip to https://storage.googleapis.com/foo-url
Created cache
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
Job succeeded
```